# Cascade Deletes Failing in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following models defined in SQLAlchemy. I want to enable cascade deletes for this relationships, where if a `Headers` record is deleted, the corresponding `Address` records should also be deleted.

```
class Headers(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity_headers'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': DB_NAME}

    main_id_h = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    valid_from_h = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=10))
    sub_id_h = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=10))
    src = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=180))

    addresses = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Addresses', cascade="all, delete-orphan", backref="addresses", lazy='selectin')

class Addresses(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entity_addresses'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': DB_NAME}

    main_id_a = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey(Headers.main_id_h), primary_key=True)
    sub_id_a = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=10), primary_key=True)
    city = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=60))
    district = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=40))
    country = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(length=60))

    headers = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Headers')
```

However, anytime I try to delete the `Headers` record, I get an `IntegrityError`. What exactly am I doing wrong?

This is the error I see,

```
IntegrityError: (mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError) 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mc_db`.`entity_addresses`, CONSTRAINT `entity_addresses_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`main_id_a`) REFERENCES `entity_headers` (`main_id_h`))
[SQL: DELETE FROM mc_db.entity_headers WHERE mc_db.entity_headers.main_id_h IN (%(main_id_h_1)s)]
[parameters: {'main_id_h_1': 16000}]
```

Comment: Works for me - can you show how you are deleting?

Comment: I have this method that I am using to delete data. It is part of a class. It is a little too long to include here, but this is base of it. The data to be deleted is passed in as a list of dictionaries,
`query = self.session.query(model)`
`for entry in entries:`
   `for key, value in entry.items():`
     `query = query.filter(getattr(model, key) == value)`

     `query.delete(synchronize_session=False)`
     `self.session.commit()`

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the end. I followed the instructions given in this article,
https://dev.to/zchtodd/sqlalchemy-cascading-deletes-8hk

In summary, I had to make the following changes to my models.

I needed to set the `ondelete` attribute of my foreign key constraints to `"cascade"`,

```
main_id_a = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey(Headers.main_id_h, ondelete="cascade"), primary_key=True)
```

In addition, I also needed to set the `passive_deletes` attribute to `True` in my relationships,

```
addresses = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Addresses', cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True, backref="addresses", lazy='selectin')
```